# Should I use いている?

Tags: grammar

E.g.: When I want to inform/ask someone regarding their current, would it be better to say 「今、駅にいています。」 or do I stick to 「今、駅にいます。」？

I know for other verbs I should conjugate to the ~ている form but is it the same with the verb いる?

Answer (score 1):

You should never use いている regardless of the situation. いる already describes a state. Stick to 駅にいます. (If I understand correctly, "It is existing" is always wrong in English.)

Alternatively, saying 駅に来ています is fine, because 来る is an action, and ている [turns it into a state](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3122/5010).